# Using Select Case in Excel VBA To Copy Worksheet from Closed Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I am trying to write an excel VBA script that will copy a specific worksheet from a closed workbook to the active workbook. The sheet to copy is determined by a checkbox and the value of a variable that is set to be the text in a specific cell. My code:

```
    Sub copysheet()
        Dim WB, ClosedWB as Workbook
        Set CheckBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CheckBox").DrawingObject
        Model = ActiveSheet.Range("K3").Text
        Const FilePath = "C:\..."
        Set WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=False, AddToMRU:=False)

        If CheckBox.Value = xlOn Then
            With ClosedWB
                Select Case Model.Text
                    Case Model = Sheet1
                        Sheets("Sheet 1 Name").Copy After:=Workbooks(WB).Sheets(Workbooks(WB).Sheets.Count)
                    Case Model = Sheet2
                        Sheets("Sheet 2 Name").Copy After:=Workbooks(WB).Sheets(Workbooks(WB).Sheets.Count)
                End Select
            End With
        End If

        If CheckBox.Value = xlOff Then
            With ClosedWB
                Select Case Model.Text
                    Case Model = Sheet3
                        Sheets("Sheet 3 Name").Copy After:=Workbooks(WB).Sheets(Workbooks(WB).Sheets.Count)
                    Case Model = Sheet4
                        Sheets("Sheet 4 Name").Copy After:=Workbooks(WB).Sheets(Workbooks(WB).Sheets.Count)
                End Select
            End With
        End If
```

I am getting a Run-Time error '424': Object Required and it highlights the Select Case Model.Text line. I have also tried Select Case Model.Value, but that didn't work. If I create a MsgBox  to display the variable model, then it displays whatever is written in the appropriate cell, so the variable value is being stored. Please help I am new at this.

Edit: Modifying Select Case Model.Text to just Select Case Model no longer results in a run-time error, but the sheets will not copy. When I run the script, it opens up the new workbook (ClosedWB), but does nothing after that. It doesn't even select the sheet that I specified it to. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Model is a string since you assigned it `ActiveSheet.Range("K3").Text`. I strongly suggest you insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and always compile before running. (`Tools`, `Options`, `Require variable Declaration` will do it automatically in every new module).

```
Select Case Model
```

Comment: I do use option explixit and dimensioned model as a string. Should I dim as variable, would that help? I removed the .text in the select case so that it looks like the code you posted above. Now i do not get any errors, but the sheets do not copy. It simply opens up the work and does not even select the correct sheet. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You are also trying to compare a string to a sheet.  Either you need to put the sheet# part in quotes if that is the text that is being entered or use sheet1.name.